# JavaScript Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

I am trying to build a path and then create a script element using JavaScript. My code is below:

```
var Form = Parse.Object.extend("Form");
var query = new Parse.Query(Form);
query.equalTo("owner",Parse.User.current())
query.find({
    success: function(form)  {                                
        var uid;                                
        for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) 
        {                                                                        
            var uid = form[i].get("uid");
            var smartFormURL = "forms.ontraport.com/v2.4/include/formEditor/genbootstrap.php?method=script&uid=" + uid + "&version=1";
            var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.src = smartFormURL;                                        
            document.getElementById("smart-form-container").appendChild(script);
        }
    },
    error: function(error)  {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

I am storing a UID in a parse class. I am retrieving the UID and then building an Ontraport SmartForm path. I then want to create a script tag and insert it into my smart form container (a div). But I a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's not this code that causes it.

Comment: And *where* do you get that SyntaxError?

Comment: This line is causing it `document.getElementById("smart-form-container").appendChild(script);` Inspection says line 1 or the `<!DOCTYPE html>` Removing the line I mentioned doesn't fire the error.

Comment: I woul definlty use Jquery for this. You just have to use $.ajax and everything should be smooth.

Comment: @SuperKevin Your URL is wrong. `var smartFormURL = "forms.ontraport.com` is missing a protocol `http://` or `https` etc. It's probably trying to load the script from your server and finding a 404 HTML file

Comment: @RafZeres jQuery would not solve this problem and would add pointless overhead